# Why is redirection not working?

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

I have created a table with two buttons - add new row and delete row. The code to delete it is called wit ajax and written in another php file. This is the code:

```
<?php

ob_start(); //eliminates buffer collisions
require_once('connect_db.php'); 
$name = $_POST['x']; 
$surname = $_POST['y']; 

$result = pg_query(connect(), "delete from lecturer where name='$name' and surname='$surname'");    
//dump the result object
var_dump($result);


//reloading the page
header("location: lecturer.php?fail=2", TRUE,307);
?>
```

And I use this ajax function to call the file:

```
$.ajax({  type: "POST",  
            url: "delete_lecturer.php",
            data: { x: names, y: surname}
        })
```

When i try to delete a row, it the row is deleted, but i have to refresh the page to see this. The log window displays the content of the main page where I have the delete button.
If I comment the line with the header(); it doesn't redirect (obviously), and the log window says "resource(2) of type(pgsql result)".
Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

PS: When I use the Add new row button it works fine. It immediately displays the newly added row. This is the code for inserting new row:

```
<?php
ob_start(); //eliminates buffer collisions
    require_once('connect_db.php'); 
    $id = time(); //creates a unique id using the unix time
    $result = pg_query(connect(), "INSERT INTO lecturer VALUES ($id, '$_POST[name]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[dep]')"); 

    //dump the result object
    var_dump($result);

    //reloading the page
    header("location: lecturer.php");

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, ill check it out and if thats the case delete my question.

Comment: Does it work if you just do a header redirect without the 307 code and replace TRUE not being set?

Comment: Remove `var_dump($result);`

Comment: Why would you redirect with status code 307 after deleting the item? A status 200 would usually indicate success, that seems more logical to me.

Comment: No, I still need to refresh to see the results. which is the actual problem - in case i didn't point out clearly because of my messy question.

Comment: Are you getting any messages in your logs? My guess is that script is dying after the row is deleted and the header function is getting called. Trying posting to it outside of ajax and see what it's doing.

Comment: I agree with @Arjan I don;t understand why you are doing a redirect.  With Ajax, typically you would get some sort of server response indicating a success and then you would do whatever javascript you need to do in the success handler to update the page (for example delete the row in question). BTW you are var_dumping data before the header.  This will never work. headers must all be sent before any content is sent from server.

Comment: If you are using AJAX wouldn't it make more sense to return true or false from your delete script and use javascript to remove the row if the delete is true

Comment: @Arjan - Good point. I was just messing around with it and forgot to change it. However, it is not the solution.

Comment: @amygrimaldi: you could use javascript to trigger a reload if the server responds that the delete was successful.

Comment: I do recommend that you not design your application this way. I would return a json from the php scripts doing the deletion and add, then let ajax handle the UI interactions.

Comment: @gnarly : The log just shows the content of the main page (the code of the main page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out (pretty much).
Short story, i dont have to redirect from the php file.
I just insert this function to redirect from ajax:

```
 .done(function( msg ) {
            location.reload();
  })
```

As to why this must be done, I do understand it, but cant quite explain.
Solution found at https://www.udemy.com/blog/jquery-refresh-page/

Comment: Having ajax handle the reload is the better way to go. I recommend returning json with true or false depending on whether the delete action actually occurred.